# python remove "many" lines from file

Tags: python, list, file-io

I am trying to remove specific line numbers from a file in python in a way such as

**./foo.py filename.txt 4 5 2919**

*Where 4 5 and 2919 are line numbers*

What I am trying to do is:

```
for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
    if i>1: # Avoiding sys.argv[0,1]
        newlist.append(int(sys.argv[i]))
```

Then:

```
count=0

generic_loop{ 
   bar=file.readline()
   count+=1
   if not count in newlist:
      print bar
}
```

it prints all the lines in original file (with blank spaces in between)

Comment: what is generic_loop? It would be better if you posted real code rather than fake code.

Comment: I was afraid it could be seemed as too specific, therefore I did in such way.

Comment: I would also encourage you to use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html). If you use `type=int` and `nargs='*'` you don't have to deal with `sys.argv` and you get excellent error/usage messages for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import sys
import os
filename= sys.argv[1]
lines = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[2:]]

#open two files one for reading and one for writing

with open(filename) as f,open("newfile","w") as f2:

#use enumerate to get the line as well as line number, use enumerate(f,1) to start index from 1
    for i,line in enumerate(f):  
        if i not in lines:     #`if i not in lines` is more clear than `if not i in line`
            f2.write(line)   
os.rename("newfile",filename)  #rename the newfile to original one
```

Note that for the generation of temporary files it's better to use [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tempfile.html) module.

Comment: Beware; this is not thread- or process-safe; if multiple processes run this program in parallel, they will probably overwrite the temporary file. Use the [`tempfile` module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tempfile.html) instead.

Comment: @phihag Thanks for the suggestion, I had never heard of `tempfile` before.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#enumerate) to determine the line number:

```
import sys
exclude = set(map(int, sys.argv[2:]))
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for num,line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if num not in exclude:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

You can remove `start=1` if you start counting at 0. In the above code, the line numbering starts with 1:

```
$ python3 so-linenumber.py so-linenumber.py 2 4 5
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

If you want to write the content to the file itself, write it to a [temporary file](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) instead of sys.stdout, and then [rename](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.rename) that to the original file name (or use [sponge](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) on the command-line), like this:

```
import os
import sys
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
exclude = set(map(int, sys.argv[2:]))
with NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as outf:
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf:
        outf.writelines(line for n,line in enumerate(inf, 1) if n not in exclude)
    os.rename(outf.name, sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Although a nice use of `tempfile`, `fileinput` has support for simple inplace editing like this in much cleaner code

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
# assumes line numbering starts with 1
# enumerate() starts with zero, so we subtract 1 from each line argument
omitlines = set(int(arg)-1 for arg in sys.argv[2:] if int(arg) > 0)
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
    filteredlines = (line for n,line in enumerate(fp) if n not in omitlines)
    sys.stdout.writelines(filteredlines)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fileinput` module has an `inplace=True` option that redirects stdout to a tempfile which is automatically renamed after for you.

```
import fileinput
exclude = set(map(int, sys.argv[2:]))

for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('filename.txt', inplace=True), start=1):
    if i not in exclude:
        print line, # fileinput inplace=True redirects stdout to tempfile
```